# Data Structure Javascript: How to create simple calculator with prompt

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have task to create simple calculator. That task required using prompt and alert for the answer. So I do this

```
let i = prompt('input');

while(i = 0) {

    x++;
    i = prompt('input');
}
alert(x);
```

that code give me alert, but not process the number

I have advise to make that value saved in system

I do

```
let i = prompt('input');

const i =[]

while(i = 0) {

    x++;
    i = prompt('input');
}
alert(x);
```

and you know that is, make error. I tried again to move the const

```
const i =[]
let i = prompt('input');



while(i = 0) {

    x++;
    i = prompt('input');
}
alert(x);
```

and still error.

I'm beginner programmer. I have this task because I'm not be able to do more advance thing before understanding data structure

I just don't know how to write logic in computer. I know the task, but I don't know how to write the code.

may be you have advice how to learn data structure more easely

thank's

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: You doesn't define the x

Answer (score 0):

## Main issue

Your first block of code has a few things that need to be fixed.

```js
let i = prompt('input');
while(i = 0) {
    x++;
    i = prompt('input');
}
alert(x);
```

This block will give an error because x is never declared. Let's declare it after (or before) declaring the `i` variable:

```js
let i = prompt('input');
let x = 0;
```

Another issue is the condition in the [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop block:

```js
while (i = 0) {
```

In the [condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while#syntax), we are assigning `0` to the `i` variable, but we want to use a comparison operator (use [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) or [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)):

```js
while(i == 0) {
```

The following fixes are applied to block one:

```js
let i = prompt('input');
let x = 0;
while (i == 0) {
  x++;
  i = prompt('input');
}
alert(x);
```

## Other thoughts

Re-declaring constants ([const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)) as you are doing in boxes two and three is not allowed, so that needs to be changed. If you want to create a constant array (`const i = []`) then you can always change the elements within the constant array (such as [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)).

```js
const i = [];
i.push("someValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, instead of having the while() val, add parseFloat() around both prompts, and have input 1 be val1 and input 2 be val 2, then, add a const aws = val1 + val2; so this will do the math for you, (parseFloat just turns the string into a number)

```js
let val1 = parseFloat(prompt('input'));
let val2 = parseFloat(prompt('input'));
const Aws = val1 + val2;
alert(Aws);
```